# Build a user session timer that runs in background and persists through page navigation

Tags: javascript

I need to build a timer to control the amount of time a user can stay logged in my website, and after that the user gets logged out automatically.

The thing is, I need it to run on the background so that when the user navigates my website it still runs and keep counting.

At the moment I am thinking about saving the amount of time the user still has in localStorage or sessionStorage:

```
sessionStorage.remainingTime = 900; 
// The user should be logged in for 15 minutes (15*60 = 900 seconds)
```

And create a web worker to keep subtracting from the remaining time every 1 second:

```
let countdownWorker = new Worker('Timer.js')
```

In my Timer.js I would have the following code:

```
// Subtract every second
setInterval(function() {
  sessionStorage.remainingTime--;
  if(sessionStorage.remainingTime === 0) {
      // I store if my user is currently logged in sessionStorage
      sesssionStorage.isUserLoggedIn = false;
  }
}, 1000);
```

**The problem is:** Web Worker does not have access to sessionStorage.

**The question is:** Should I store my remainingTime variable somewhere else or should I use a different API that is not Web Worker? I need something that has access to sessionStorage because my variable to control if user is logged in is stored there and I can't change that because of project restrictions.

Comment: Why not just use localstorage (for tabs) and setInterval function on page load?

Comment: This strategy is open to user manipulation via Chrome DevTools. The right way to do this is with server-side code (PHP, ASP, Node.js, etc) and AJAX. That also allows the timing system to transcend page navigation.

Comment: Depending on what library you're using for authentication you might have some open source tools to help you. For example with OpenID Connect you can use OIDC Client.

Answer (score 0):

Does the webworker need access to the sessionStorage? Why not just use a global variable in the webworker and have it message back when the session is expired, or if you want to show a timing out message then when the session reaches a certain threshold. You can let the worker know when theres activity on the page to extend the session.

On a side note I recommend using an expires at date versus a length of time when using a timeout since when the tab is in the background it will get throttled and wont run at exactly every second. Using a date allows you to do `timeLeft = expiresAtTime - currentTime` at a certain interval so sync back to where it should be.

Comment: I updated the question now. Ineed access to sessionStorage because the variable to control if user is logged in is stored there

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can approach it in a different way.

When the user logs in, you store the expiration time and then just create on page load a `setInterval` function that checks if `Date.now() > expirationDate`, if true > log out the user.

As mentioned by @gibberish, this is not secure at all since it's client side and the user can mess up the clock. If you want something more robust, you need your server to handle this kind of things.